# Small capitalize in section tilte

Tags: fonts, small-caps

I've to use a small capitalized in a section title. I've put this `\textsc{ctl}` in the title, but the output doesn't show small capitalized letters. Anyway, the text is properly printed in the table of contents. I think that this issue is related to the default font used for the titles: how can I modify it in order to properly show the small capitalized text?

I'm using a custom template to write my PhD thesis. Looking at the class sources I've found this:

```
\LoadClass[10pt,%
       twoside=true,%
       open=right,%
       cleardoublepage=empty,%
       chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
```

I suppose the class is based on `scrbook`. Source of the class can be viewed here: http://pastebin.com/22Sq1Vt2

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Could you provide some more information, like which document class you use and how are titles defined?

Comment: Which document class do you use? Do you load any packages that affect the appearance of sectioning headers? Do you need ordinary or **bold** small-caps letters?

Comment: I need ordinary small-caps letters. I've edited the question with more information about the class I'm using. Thank you.

Comment: The code shows that your document format is based in `scrbook` but this doesn't mean that some other further parts of this `.cls` file doesn't fix fonts and titles. So we are almost like before you edited the question. Please, load the class or at least provide a link to it.

Comment: Do you want all the section titles to be small caps or only one word in the section title i.e., `Ctl` to be small caps?

Comment: I'm very sorry. I post here [http://pastebin.com/22Sq1Vt2](http://pastebin.com/22Sq1Vt2) the source of the class.

Comment: @HarishKumar, only one word.

Comment: Then use `Here is a section {\normalfont\textsc{Ctl}}` or `{\normalfont\scshape Ctl}`

Comment: @HarishKumar It works. Thx. Is it too hard to add bold too?

Comment: @GilbertoT. You need to use a font that provides a bold small cap variant for example adding `\usepackage{libertine}` and just `\textsc{Ctl}` will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make only one word in small caps, then use

```
Here is a section {\normalfont\textsc{Ctl}}
```

or

```
Here is a section {\normalfont\scshape Ctl}
```

If you want to make this bold too, you have to use a font that offers this. For example `libertine` font can be used (`\usepackage{libertine}`). With this just `\textsc{Ctl}` should be enough.